# What does beyonce means by spun gold out of this hard life

Tags: meaning

[From Beyoncé's *Lemonade*: album transcript by [Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/articles/156559-transcript-of-beyonces-lemonade-because-the-words-are-just-as-important-as-the-music)]

> Grandmother, the alchemist, *you **spun** gold **out** of this hard life*, conjured beauty from the things left behind. Found healing where it did not live. Discovered the antidote in your own kit. Broke the curse with your own two hands. You passed these instructions down to your daughter who then passed it down to her daughter

So I’ve been surfing on the internet trying to find what does **spin out** mean to make sense out of what Beyoncé said but I don’t seem to find it.  Is it an idiom, can you help out thanks

Answer (score 2):

Beyoncé also refers to her grandmother as an alchemist.  [Alchemy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alchemy) was the medieval science that tried to convert ordinary metals into gold.  The term "alchemy" is also used as a metaphor for a seemingly magical process.

In the story of [Rumpelstiltskin](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Rum.shtml), a miller claims that his daughter can spin straw into gold.

To "[spin](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spin)" is "to make thread by twisting fibres , or to produce something using thread" (example: "The final stage of the production of cotton is when it is spun into thread").

A metaphorical alchemist who spins gold out of the difficulties of life is managing to make money through a seemingly impossible, magical process.

It is relevant to note here that Beyoncé's grandmother was a seamstress (i.e. a woman who earns her living through sewing).

According to the *[Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/music/news/beyoncs-new-album-why-is-it-called-lemonade-plus-everything-else/)*, the album is "an ode to overcoming hardship, turning things around, and triumphing over adversity" and "references both the singer’s personal struggles, and some of the wider issue faced by black women today and throughout history".

The lyrics also refer to a lemonade recipe being passed down through the generations.  Lemons are a similar colour to gold.  And according to the Telegraph, the title also references the phrase "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade".  According to a commenter at [phrases.org.uk](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/952.html):

> To me, it means, make the best of what you're given. It has similarities to phrases such as "play the cards you're dealt" and to a certain extent "every cloud has a silver lining".

Comment: Not enough reputation to edit without it going in to the review queue--you've got a typo in the first sentence, "hold" for "gold".

Answer (score 0):

To **spin** something **out of** a substance, means to produce it, as on a [spinning wheel](https://www.google.com/search?q=spinning%20wheel&num=20&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=iu&pf=m&ictx=1&fir=VgwnJPZC2jxcVM%253A%252C7hsP33xZbVfxyM%252C_&usg=__0p2Yo96jNS22c0D0PjGWB6hAOl0%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF7KKJ4vLWAhWLdSYKHbLrCawQ_h0I-wEwIQ#imgrc=-ExGjwyPLb-e8M:), using the substance as the base material.

The artist spins a golden thread *from* the difficulties of life.

The artist spins a golden thread *out of* the difficulties of life.

> She made a cake **out of** flour, milk, sugar, eggs, and vanilla.
>
> In origami, animal shapes and flowers are made **out of** paper.